# GDI+ Text Flickering and Now with Black background

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I'm working on a windows desktop application and I noticed to my dismay that my text was flickering so upon searching I found two methods - return true for erasebkgnd and double buffering. The first method didn't do anything and the second made my background all black for some reason and it still flickers.

Below is where I call paint and the buffering:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC screen = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);   
            putImage(screen, hWnd);
            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            HDC memdc;
            auto hbuff = BeginBufferedPaint(screen, &rc, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, NULL, &memdc);
            EndBufferedPaint(hbuff, TRUE);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); } break;
```

and this next part is the putImage function

```
void putImage(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd)
{
    Graphics graphic(hdc);
    graphic.DrawImage(Image::FromFile(filePath), 10, 10);
    RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
}
```

I was wondering what the problem was and if there is a fix for this.

Comment: The presented code can't reproduce this issue. Can you show a mini, complete and reproducible sample? What do you want to achieve using `BeginBufferedPaint`? `graphic.DrawImage` do the drawing work actually.

Comment: I read that to stop the flickering, I need to put something called a double buffer, which I'm not completely sure on. So, I decided to try out the solution present there which was the lines below putImagein the wmpaint case down to endbufferedpaint. When I comment that part out, the black window disappears, but the flickering is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my background all black

This issue is due to not filling the your background. You can fill your background before draw the image like this:

```
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        FillRect(screen, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));
```

> flickering

This issue is due to not using [`BeginBufferedPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-beginbufferedpaint) in correct manner. Call `BeginBufferedPaint` before drawing the image like this:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC screen = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HPAINTBUFFER hbuff = BeginBufferedPaint(ps.hdc, &ps.rcPaint, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, NULL, &screen);
    if (hbuff)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        FillRect(screen, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));
        putImage(screen, hWnd);

        hr = EndBufferedPaint(hbuff, TRUE);
    }

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); } break;
```

And don't forget to call [`BufferedPaintInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-bufferedpaintinit) and [`BufferedPaintUnInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-bufferedpaintuninit). For example like this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    hr = BufferedPaintInit();
}
break;

//...

case WM_DESTROY:
{
    BufferedPaintUnInit();
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}
break;
```

**Update:** The complete code.

```
void putImage(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd)
{
    Graphics graphic(hdc);
    Image* image = Image::FromFile(L"path-to\\test.png");
    Status status = graphic.DrawImage(image, 10, 10);
    RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD err;
    HRESULT hr;
    static HDC memdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hr = BufferedPaintInit();
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC screen = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HPAINTBUFFER hbuff = BeginBufferedPaint(ps.hdc, &ps.rcPaint, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, NULL, &screen);
        if (hbuff)
        {
            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            FillRect(screen, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));
            putImage(screen, hWnd);

            hr = EndBufferedPaint(hbuff, TRUE);
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); } break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        BufferedPaintUnInit();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I was wondering what the hr variable is when you set it equal to EndBufferedPaint. Is it just for checking the return value to see if it worked or not?

Comment: Also the screen is actually flickering worse than before for some reason :/

Comment: @ShadyAF I update my answer with the complete code which works for me. You can have a try.

Comment: Hm... Still doesn't work. Does it have to with the fact that I added a static control text box? Not sure why it's happening. Also I found out that if I comment out RedrawWindow in the putImage, the control stops flickering, but the window isn't updated now so it can't even display the image. Also, I was wondering why you put m_pf in front of the bufferedpaint function calls.

Comment: @ShadyAF Please use a clean application without other controls in it and try again. Or post your complete code that reproduce the issue. Use m_pf because I find the function from DLL and rename it for me. I've updated my answer to remove it. You can ignore it.

Comment: I can reproduce the control flickering issue with your complete code. Remove `RedrawWindowor` use `RECT updateRect = { 0 };
 updateRect.left = 10;
 updateRect.top = 10;
 updateRect.right = updateRect.left + image->GetWidth();
 updateRect.bottom = updateRect.top + image->GetHeight();
 RedrawWindow(hWnd, &updateRect, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);` both options work for me. Image and control display correctly and no flickers.

Comment: You're talking about replacing redrawwindow in the putimage function for all that right?

Comment: @ShadyAF Yes, remove this line `RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);` or replace it using code lines in my last comment.

Comment: but if I remove redrawwindow, the static control stays there, convering the picture after I load it in

Comment: @ShadyAF It seems your picture is large and there is a overlap issue between the image and static control. To solve this issue you may design your layout, however, it is a different topic from your initial question. If the flicker and black background issues are solved you can open a new question.

Comment: Well, I tried repalcing redrawwindow with your code above but none of my controls are visible. When I try just straight up not redrawing the window, the control just stays there whereas I want it to be gone.

Comment: @ShadyAF Copy exactly your complete code and replace the `RedrawWindow` line with code lines shared in my comment, it works for me. I take a snapshot of the window and code. Please check my update answer.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it worked when I ran it again when it didn't before.